# Cannot read Video File OpenCV3

Tags: opencv3.0

I am trying to use OpenCV3 for video file reading.

```
string packageRootPath = ros::package::getPath("visensor_dgem");
string videoFullPath = packageRootPath + "/dump/Video.avi";
cout << videoFullPath << endl;
cv::VideoCapture cap;
bool flag = cap.open( videoFullPath );
if( flag )
    cout << "flag true\n";
else
    cout << "flag false\n";
```

The path to the video file is correct. I am guessing my issue has to do with the video codecs. The program compiles file, however when I run the code I get `flag false`. I have tried to open the file with `fstream` and it opens successfully, so I am sure of the path and permissions etc.

I am on ubuntu 14.04. I have installed opencv3 from source code. Here is the config of my opencv:
(even more details of my installation here : https://kusemanohar.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/opencv-pro-built/)

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so dc1394 avcodec avformat avutil swscale /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so vtkCharts vtkCommon vtkFiltering vtkGenericFiltering vtkGeovis vtkGraphics vtkHybrid vtkIO vtkImaging vtkInfovis vtkParallel vtkRendering vtkViews vtkVolumeRendering vtkWidgets dl m pthread rt tbb cudart nppc nppi npps cufft
--     3rdparty dependencies:       ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 hal cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video viz cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java python2 python3
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.2.1)
--     QT OpenGL support:           NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 5.8.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.35.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/mpkusex/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.6)
--     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.2 interface 7000)
--     Use OpenMP:                  YES
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use pthreads for parallel for:
--                                  NO
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 7.5)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
--     Use fast math:               NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/mpkusex/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.6)
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/mpkusex/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mpkusex/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/buil
```

Relevant section of my CMakeLists.txt. I am using opencv with catkin (ros - ros.org) which is essentially same as cmake. I can run my other opencv stuff like edge detection, image reading etc.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(visensor_dgem)

    ## Find catkin macros and libraries
    ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
    ## is used, also find other catkin packages
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      cv_bridge
      image_transport
      roscpp
      tf
      message_generation    
        )
    find_package( message_generation )

    find_package( OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui flann calib3d video )

add_executable( videoReader
    src/videoReader.cpp
)

target_link_libraries( videoReader
  ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

How can I resolve this?